# Преобразовать std::string в std::wstring

Tags: c++, строки, кодировка

Как `std::string` перевести в `std::wstring`?

Допустим:

```
std::string s = "some string";
std::wstring ws = f(s);
```

Как может быть реализована `f()`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Много способов..., вот парочка...

```
//1
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
std::string str = converter.to_bytes(L"Hello world");
std::wstring wstr = converter.from_bytes("Hello world");

//2
std::string str("Hello world!!!");
std::wstring wstr(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Comment: Второй работает только для однобайтовых символов

Answer (score 1):

В C++17 заголовочный файл `<codecvt>` стал *deprecated*, как и шаблонные классы `std::wstring_convert` и `std::wbuffer_convert`. В С++20 из-за отсутствия альтернативных способов преобразований эти фичи пока не были удалены. Так что на данный момент нет способа сделать это в общем случае без использования сторонних библиотек (либо устаревшего функционала).

[Предложение сделать <codecvt> deprecated](https://wg21.link/p0618).

[Рассмотрение удаления указанных фич (D.15 и D.16 соответственно)](https://wg21.link/p0619).