# TCHAR в std::string конвертация

Tags: c++, строки

```
TCHAR *tchar;
std::string s = "";
s = tchar;
```

Как сделать конвертацию? Сил уже нету ничего искать

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/331546/string-to-wstring а это не оно?

Comment: @pavel там наоборот.

Comment: Вы сначала расскажите откуда возникла такая задача. Почему вдруг тип-"перевертыш" `TCHAR` вдруг конвертируется в тип с конкретной фиксированной шириной символа `string`? Если вы писали универсальный код, то что тут делает `string`? Если вы писали код именно для широкого `wchar_t`, то что тут делает `TCHAR`? Я не говорю, что такая задача не может возникнуть, но смутные сомнения таки мучают.

Answer (score 1):

TCHAR является зависимым от используемой кодировки, необходимо делать макропроверку:

```
TCHAR *tchar;
std::string s;

#ifndef UNICODE
    s = t;
#else
    std::wstring wStr = t;
    s = std::string(wStr.begin(), wStr.end());
#endif

std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

Ну или если хотите чтобы работало только у вас:

```
TCHAR *tchar;
std::wstring wStr = t;
std::string s = std::string(wStr.begin(), wStr.end());
```

Comment: только не забудьте проинициализировать tchar!

Comment: Чего мы добьёмся усечением `wchar_t` до `char`?

Comment: Что такое `t` в ваших примерах кода?

Answer (score -2):

В настройках проекта в visual studio сделайте так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и что после этого код в вопросе станет корректным?

Comment: Теперь когда я делаю ввод с консоли, вместо массива символов, у меня считывается только первый и получается строка с одним символом

Comment: @pavel, он начнет работать, да. Но, возможно, не совсем корректно.

Comment: Вы бы ответ с SO полностью цитировали, а не кусками
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6006371/698689

Comment: Я обычно ставлю ссылки на ответ на SO, но в этот раз поленился, прошу прощения.

Comment: Вообще-то это совершенно правильный ответ, если учесть, что его омысленность в точности соответствует осмысленности вопроса.

Comment: @user211406 Что вы там делаете в своем "вводе с консоли" нам отсюда не видно, но данный ответ - совершенно правилен в рамках вашей постановки вопроса.