# Конвертация std::string в std::wstring

Tags: c++, строки

Доброго времени суток. Способов несколько знаю, вот к примеру:

```
  std::string str("abcdefg");
  std::wstring output(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Но проблема становится ребром, если в экземпляре класса str используются русские символы. output создаётся не с теми символами, что были в str. Как победить проблему? Заранее спасибо.
P.S.: вопрос короткий, не относящийся к главному: под сколько элементов по-умолчанию выделяет класс vector память. Если использовать его конструктор по-умолчанию? Спасибо.

Comment: А в какой кодировке ваша узкая строка?

Comment: Вы можете опросить у вектора capacity. Думаю, будет 0.

Comment: SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
SetConsoleCP(1251);

Comment: Да, capacity вернул ноль, спасибо. Не подумал как-то...

Comment: Конвертация как написано в вопросе катит только для ASCII-строк. Вам нужно использовать кодировку в явном виде. Подтянутся гуру C++ и вспомнят, как именно это делается :)

Comment: Но проще всего вообще не работать с узкими строками, как мне кажется.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразовать std::string в std::wstring](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/331546/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-stdstring-%d0%b2-stdwstring)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если кодировка CP1251, то как-то так:

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

// "костыль", чтобы наш codecvt имел публичный деструктор,
// как того требует wstring_convert
template<class Facet> 
struct deletable_facet : Facet
{
    template<class ...Args>
    deletable_facet(Args&& ...args) : Facet(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
    ~deletable_facet() {}
};

// собственно определяем "конвертер" из узкой в широкую строку и обратно
using convert_type = std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>;
std::wstring_convert<deletable_facet<convert_type>, wchar_t> converter;

int main() {
    std::string s = "йцукен";
    // string в wstring
    std::wstring ws = converter.from_bytes(str);
    // обратное преобразование
    std::string ss = converter.to_bytes(wstr);
}
```

Для UTF-8 нужно только по другому определить `convert_type` и (опционально) `converter`:

```
using convert_type = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;
```

То есть в случае, если вы используете предопределенный `codecvt_*`, можно опустить использование `deletable_facet`.

[Документация](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt), на которую я ориентировался.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!