# Как преобразовать аргумент из std::string в LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, winapi

Кусок кода для проверки интернет соединения:

```
#include <Wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")

bool CheckConnection(const std::string InternetLink)
{
    if (!InternetCheckConnectionW(InternetLink.c_str, FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0))
    return 0;
        return 1;
}
```

**Мне выдаёт ошибку:**
*не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "const std::string" в "LPCWSTR*

Затем хотел вызвать её примерно так:

```
is(!CheckConnection("http://google.com") {...}
```

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. Приведенный вам код такой ошибки выдать не может. Не надо выдумывать, приводите реальный код.

Comment: @AnT, может. Вопрошающий использует `W`-вариант функции, принимающий не `char*`, а `wchar_t*`.

Comment: @Arhad: У вопрошающего отсутствует `()` после `c_str`. Это уже исключает появление такой ошибки. И это говорит о том, что код, который он компилирует - этот не тот код, который он привел здесь. Два `return` идущих подряд тоже намекают на то, что здесь приведена какая-то бНОПНЯ, а не реальный код.

Comment: @AnT, Пример проверки интернет  соединения взял с левого борда) для теста, чтобы проверить.

Comment: @GooliveR: Это замечательно. Но компилировали вы *не тот* код, который привели здесь. Тот код, который вы привели здесь, такую ошибку породить не может в принципе. Здесь рекомендуется приводить *реальный* код, а не "фантазии по мотивам"

Comment: @AnT, С чего у Вас такое подозрение? ^_^ Именно этот код Я и компилировал.

Comment: @GooliveR: Я уже детально описал выше, откуда у меня такое подозрение. Никаких сомнений тут нет. Именно этот код ни при каких обстоятельствах не выдаст "не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "const std::string" в "LPCWSTR". Вместо того, чтобы спорить в комментариях, аккуратно сравните код и вы увидите разницу.

Comment: @AnT, Ну главное что проблема решена!

Comment: @GooliveR: На SO "более главной" считается полезность вопроса и ответа будущим читателям, а не то, что "моя проблема решена". Тем более что в вашем случае разумнее было бы воспользоваться просто `InternetCheckConnection` (никакого `W` или `A`), предварительно настроив проект на обычные символы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LPCWSTR` — это Unicode-строка. В C++ её аналогом является `std::wstring` (обратите внимание на префикс `w`).

Используемый же вами `std::string` — это строка в однобайтной кодировке, и её можно преобразовать максимум в `LPCSTR`.

Соответственно, вам нужно использовать не Юникодный `InternetCheckConnectionW()`, а однобайтносимвольный `InternetCheckConnectionA()`.

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы не приходилось делать лишних преобразований строк, можно пользоваться таким нехитрым макросом:

```
#if defined(UNICODE)
    #define _tstring wstring
#else
    #define _tstring string
#endif
```

Теперь, в проекте замените все *std::string* на **std::_tstring**.
И Вам уже не придется конвертировать строки на ровном месте. В STL есть и другие сюрпризы для winapi (например to_string/to_wstring). Это решение подходит и для них.

То же самое касается A/W, @AnT прав: не надо явно вызывать InternetCheckConnection**A** или InternetCheckConnection**W**, если у Вас на то нет особых требований (а судя по коду, их нет). Вызывайте InternetCheckConnection без постфиксов.

И не забывайте про текстовый помошник в windows - макрос **TEXT** или **_T**.
Правильный вызов CheckConnection такой:

```
is(!CheckConnection(TEXT("http://google.com")) {...}
```

Comment: Буду знать теперь, спасибо за совет. Воспользуюсь в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 0):

гляньте тута:
[Конвертация std::string в std::wstring](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667466/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-stdstring-%D0%B2-stdwstring?rq=1)

да и передавать в функцию лучше наверно не const std::string, а const std::string&