# Метод который возвращает функцию получения папки Temp

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Можно ли создать отдельный метод получения папки Temp?

например чтобы не писать каждый раз функцию:

```
TCHAR myPath[MAX_PATH];
GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, myPath);
```

Сделать метод который будет возвращать путь до папки `GetTempPath`

Comment: Сомнительная выгода от такой обертки будет...

Comment: Обьявите myPath глобальной, при запуске один раз вызвать GetTempPath, а дальше берите себе путь.

Comment: Вопрос переформулировать. Потому что "возвращаемая функция папки темп" с такой формулировкой врядли кто согласится. Не понятно функцию вы хотите вернуть, или функция возвратная...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не сочтите за назойливость, но я бы это сделал так:

```
#if defined(UNICODE)
    #define _tstring wstring
#else
    #define _tstring string
#endif

std::_tstring myGetTempPath()
{
    TCHAR myPath[MAX_PATH];
    GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, myPath);

    return myPath;
}
```

шапку можно менять на выбор:

```
#if defined(UNICODE)
    #define _tstring wstring
#else
    #define _tstring string
#endif
```

или

```
namespace std{
    typedef basic_string<TCHAR> _tstring;
}
```

или

```
namespace std{
#if defined(UNICODE)
    typedef wstring _tstring;
#else
    typedef string _tstring;
#endif
}
```

можно наверное еще что-нибудь придумать :)

Я сам для себя уже давно выбрал шапку №1, и всегда ее [использую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/743423/8766), т.к. она простая. Почти всем она понятна и не требует каких-то глубоких знаний для поддержки кода.

Answer (score 1):

А если переделать в

```
string tempPath()
{
    TCHAR myPath[MAX_PATH];
    GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, myPath);    
    return myPath;
}
```

?

Впрочем, поскольку вряд ли во время работы программы будет меняться местоположение папки `Temp`, не будет большим грехом сделать ее имя глобальной переменной и инициализировать только один раз, после чего просто использовать эту глобальную строку...

Comment: @Abyx Ну да, тут я не очень силен, в этих MS-извращениях...

Comment: а тут все с точностью наоборот: `TCHAR` надо заменить на `char`, а `GetTempPath` - на `GetTempPathA`, раз уж решили использовать `std::string`. А вообще, [лучше не ограничивать типы так явно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/743423/8766).

Comment: @mega Это все в любом случае привязка к конкретному компилятору. Тогда нужно в тэгах `visual-c++` прописывать, а не просто `c++`.

Comment: Какая разница, чем это собирать? Лишь бы SDK поддерживало. Вы просто попробуйте собрать свой код в проекте Unicode.

Comment: @mega Напишите лучше свой вариант.

Answer (score 1):

1) что мешает оформить это как функцию, типа

```
std::wstring myGetTempPath()
{
    TCHAR myPath[MAX_PATH];
    GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, myPath);

    return std::wstring(myPath);
}
```

Записать ее в свою библиотеку, типа utils.h и вызывать где душе удобно

2) тоже самое, но не отдельной функцией, а через синглтон, тогда вызывать можно так

```
std::wstring res = MyUtils::GetInstance()->GetTempPath();
```

3) записать функционал в виде статического метода в класс , тогда вызывать можно так

```
std::wstring res = MyUtils::GetTempPath();
```

**P.S.**

Как тебе уже ответили - если tmp папка не меняется, то можно только один раз вычислить путь и дальше его возвращать (правда вопрос, стоит ли такая оптимизация сил).

Для этого как раз синглтон подойдет - первый его вызов приведет к определению пути, все последующие вызовы будут просто возвращать результат, без дополнительного обращения к WinAPI функциям

Comment: `отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string [с _Elem=wchar_t, _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>, _Alloc=std::allocator<wchar_t>]", соответствующие списку аргументов` - Многобайтовая кодировка у меня стоит.

Comment: GooliveR не понял, это откуда вылезло?
Ты #include <string> подключил (не <string.h> а именно <string>
как советовали ниже - можно tstring использовать - ну чтобы уж к твоему TCHAR приспособить

Comment: Да подключил `<string>` вылезло на этой строчке: `return std::wstring(myPath);` Нашёл [Решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106473/problem-with-tstring-typedef)

Comment: `TCHAR` тут надо заменить на `wchar_t`, а `GetTempPath` - на `GetTempPathW`, раз уж решили использовать `wstring`.