# SFML функция замены L

Tags: c++, кодировка, sfml, кириллица

Не знаю как это правильно называется, поэтому и не могу найти аналог.
сить такова есть выводить кирилицу текст в SFML через (sf::string) то выводятся иероглифы(так понимаю неверная кодировка).
Решение, добавление L перед значением переменной.

```
sf:String = "Кирилица" -> sf:String = L"Кирилица".
```

Но как преобразоваться Std::string в sf:String c темиже правилами как у L.

Comment: https://utf8everywhere.org, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/910937/312941

Comment: В конструкторе `sf:String` есть второй параметр, посредством которого можно указывать кодировку входящей строки.